# Thermal radiation in a spherical object with a cavity in it

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Consider this problem is related to the radiation of heat from an object. The object is a sphere with a cavity. It has an outer radius $R_o$, and the radius of the cavity is $R_i$. The emissivity of the outer surface is $e_o$, and the inner surface is 1. Now, for simplicity, the temperature of the surroundings is given as 0 Kelvin. The initial temperature of the object is 1000 kelvin and we have to calculate the time taken for the temperature to go down to 500 kelvin if radiation is the only way by which heat can be transferred out. (subscript 'o' stands for outer and 'i' for inner)

Here, we can neglect any heat transfer in the inner cavity, as it absorbs all the heat which is incident on it, So any heat which it radiated would just flow back into itself. Thus, we only need to evaluate the outer surface's radiation, and that's simple with the stefan-boltzmann equation.

But, my question here is that what would happen if the emissivity of the inner cavity is not equal to 1? My teacher said that you would then consider the radiation by inner surface too, and just use the same formula- if earlier we were using $E = e_o\sigma A_o T^4$, now we would use $E = e_o\sigma A_o T^4 + e_i\sigma A_i T^4$

This just does not seem right to me. Here we are completely ignoring that some of the radiations will be absorbed again by the inner cavity.

What I think is that the cavity is closed, so there is no way that the energy could just be radiated out and not be re-absorbed back into the cavity. No matter how much or how little energy is radiated and absorbed, it will stay in the system and not make a big contribution to the lowering of temperatures. This assumes that the cavity does not have any air in it.

So, what would actually happen in this case?

Comment: If the system is closed, both bodies will reach the same temperature at equilibrium. Equilibrium thermodynamics cannot calculate how long this will take.